# How can I detect string literals in code?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I want to write string detecting function for my obfuscator, I've stuck at debugging it, I can write pattern for strings like `cout<<"Hello world"` or `cout<<"2+2=4"`

but not for

```
cout<<"2+2"<<"Trolll";
cout<<"asd \" trololo";
```

simply I just want to extract things which are between " and ", actually I tried

```
["][\x20-\x74]*["]
```

but for e.g.

```
cout<<"asdfg"<<"asdsfgh";
```

it gives me `"asdfg"<<"asdfgh"`, not `"asdfg"`.

Any ideas how to build the expression for string extraction?

Comment: Regular expressions are a poor choice for this problem. For example, unbalanced quotation marks in comments will mess it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular expressions, by default, are *greedy*. This means that they try to match as much as possible. There are several ways of preventing this. The easiest is to just make them *non-greedy*. You can make the quantifier `*` non-greedy by appending `?`:

```
"[\x20-\x74]*?"
```

(Incidentally, there’s no need for the `[…]` around the quotes.)

However, it’s helpful to be explicit and precise in descriptions. One reason for this is that the above expression is still buggy. For instance, it doesn’t match `"\""` correctly.

A string literal in C++ is quite well-defined, and your definition simply doesn’t match it. The actual definition (§2.14.3 of the standard) is (simplified): a *char-sequence* surrounded by `"`, where a *char-sequence* is a sequence of zero or more characters except `"`, `\` and newline, or an *escape-sequence*.

An *escape-sequence*`, in turn, is defined as either *simple*, *octal* or *hexadecimal*. Taken together, this leaves us with (again, slightly simplified):

```
"([^"\\]|\\(['"?\\abfnrtv]|[0-7]+|x[0-9a-fA-F]+))*"
```

– no need for the non-greedy specifier now, since we explicitly exclude `"` from matching earlier, unless escaped.

Comment: Your expression is still buggy, I spent 2 hours on this and still can't make it work for all strings :_____:

Comment: @encoree1337 You didn’t provide enough detail. I’ve tested my expressions on your test case and they (unsurprisingly) both work. What’s more, I’m fairly confident that, simple typos notwithstanding, the second expression echoes the C++ specification fairly closely (but intentionally ignores more complex C++11 string literals). That said, heed Raymond’s comment above: regex is the wrong tool here.

Comment: One thing this regex misses is UCNs: `"\u0040"`. I'd simplify by allowing `\\.`: there's no need to reject invalid escape sequences, since they won't appear in a correct program anyway. Something a bit rarer (but still used on occasion) is a line splicing. And for completeness, something far more rarer that you probably shouldn't even try to handle is a trigraph: `"??/""`.